# background color is not visible in firefox 4

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the fiddle Im working with : 
http://jsfiddle.net/SxZGE/

The html part of code is:

```
<div  class="Right green">
    <h2>
      <div class="number colorV"> 8.123456 </div>
      <div id="text"> huh-fjiuetie</div>
    </h2>
    <div  class="Right-after green-after"></div>
</div>
```

Problem: My browser is firefox4 and Im not able to see the background color i.e. green color below the text(which is visible in higher versions of firefox)

Can someone give a solution for this(in order to see the background color) without changing the browser or upgrading it( i.e, my browser must be firefox4 and this page should be rendered as required)

Comment: Why are you using a 2.5 year old browser?

Comment: Maybe FF4 doesn't support `linear-gradient`. Try `-moz-linear-gradient`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the vendor-prefixed value of `-moz-linear-gradient`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SxZGE/13/) is an updated version of your fiddle.

If you wish to support many browsers and versions, don't forget to add the other vendor-prefixed values for the other browsers, and add a fallback `background: #005b26;` **before** the gradient rules.

Your finished class would look something like this:

```css
.green {
    background: #005b26;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #1d9755,#005b26,#002000);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to left, #1d9755,#005b26,#002000);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to left, #1d9755,#005b26,#002000);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(to left, #1d9755,#005b26,#002000);
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #1d9755,#005b26,#002000);
}
```

[Here](http://prefixr.com) is a tool you can use to add the vendor prefixes to your CSS.

Comment: in this case instead of the linear gradient im getting a constant background which u set in the first line

Comment: @user2613399 Yes, that's the fallback for cases when the browser doesn't support the other values.

Comment: So what should i do in this case?

Comment: @user2613399 If your browser _does_ actually support `-moz-linear-gradient`, then I can't fathom a reason for why the gradient is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your .green class to the following:

```css
.green {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to left, #1d9755,#005b26,#002000);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #1d9755,#005b26,#002000);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #1d9755,#005b26,#002000);
}
```

Comment: it is not working that way also. does linear gradient work in firefox4?

Comment: It says it works from FF 3.6 and upwards, provided you use the -moz prefix.

Comment: @WebNovice You'll want to put `linear-gradient` below the others.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this vendor prefixed CSS rule:

```
-moz-linear-gradient(to left, #1d9755,#005b26,#002000)
```

"-moz-linear-gradient" support from FF 3.6+

Comment: Just so you know; vendor prefixes aren't "browser hacks".